# Calling OnTime method in a Custom Class

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the `.OnTime` method in a class module, but can't figure out how to call a procedure in the class. All of the `.OnTime` examples I've seen refer to using the method from a standard code module rather than a custom class. Is there any way of calling a procedure in the class module rather than a standard code module?

@Alex P: Updated to include code. Here is the Class Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    MsgBox "Success"

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), _
                                    Procedure:="Test"

End Sub
```

And the Standard Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestOnTime()

    Dim OnTime As CCOnTime

    Set OnTime = New CCOnTime

End Sub
```

I've also tried `Procedure:="CClass.Test"`

Comment: Can you show us your class module please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for magic - VBA is a comprehensive tool but it is not magic.

The reason is that every Class module is simply a template which can be instantiated any number of times in the application code. Excel could not hope to correctly guess which particular instantiation of the Class module is the correct one on which to invoke the method. You are responsible for making this decision and managing the references to the appropriate Class instance.

Ah you say - But there is no private data/references being used by the method I want called. It is a *static method*.  Well the answer to that is that VBA does not support static methods on Class modules, only on Standard modules. Any method that you wish to declare to the environment as being static *is declared as being static by being included in a standard module*.

So, place your call-back method in a Standard module, and declare a private member that holds a reference to the particular instance of the Class that you wish to handle the event.

Comment: I thought as much. I had been calling a procedure in a Standard Module prviously, but was hoping for a solution to keep everything encapsulated in the Class. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but the call-back needs to be bounced back into the object from a Standard Module or a Worksheet Module or Thisworkbook.

Here is an example that pulses a value in a worksheet cell.
The timer is (almost) encapsulated in the cOnTime Class.

A cOnTime Object is instantiated in the host worksheet, whose code module can have a property to set the pulse time as well as the call-back routine.

If you protect the sheet, it will start pulsing and you can stop it by un-protecting the sheet.
If you navigate away from the host sheet, the timer is killed and if you navigate back it re-starts (as long as the sheet is protected).

Class cOnTime

```
Option Explicit
Const DEFPulseTime = "PulseTime"
Const DEFearliestTime As Long = 5
Const DEFlatestTime As Long = 15

Public WithEvents wb As Workbook
Public ws As Worksheet

Private DoWhen As String
Public mPulseTime As Long
Public mNextTime As Double
Property Let callBackDoWhen(cb As String)
    DoWhen = "'" & wb.Name & "'!" & ws.CodeName & "." & cb      'e.g. 'wb Name.xlsm'!Sheet1.kickdog
End Property
Private Function PulseTime() As Long
    On Error Resume Next
         PulseTime = CallByName(ws, DEFPulseTime, VbGet)
         If Err.number <> 0 Then
             PulseTime = DEFearliestTime
         End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Property Get designMode() As Boolean
    designMode = Not ws.ProtectContents
End Property
Public Sub kickDog()
Const myName As String = "kickDog"
Dim psMessage As String
    If ws Is ActiveSheet And Not designMode Then

        mNextTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, mPulseTime)

        On Error Resume Next
        Application.OnTime mNextTime, DoWhen
        On Error GoTo 0

    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
Public Sub killDog()

    If ws Is Nothing Or mNextTime = 0 Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime mNextTime, DoWhen, , False
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim errorContext As String

    On Error GoTo enableAndExit
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error GoTo 0

    callBackDoWhen = DEFDoWhen
    callBackPulseTime = DEFPulseTime
    mPulseTime = PulseTime
    kickDog

    Exit Sub
enableAndExit:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            errorContext = "ws"
        ElseIf wb Is Nothing Then
            errorContext = "wb"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
Const myName As String = "Class_Terminate"

    On Error Resume Next
    killDog
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Private Sub wb_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    wb_Open
End Sub

Private Sub wb_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    killDog
End Sub
Private Sub wb_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    killDog
End Sub
Private Sub wb_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then killDog
End Sub
```

In Worksheet Module

```
Option Explicit

Const cPulseTime As Long = 1

Dim mOnTime As cOnTime
Property Get PulseTime() As Long
    PulseTime = cPulseTime
End Property
'****************************************
'Timer call-back for cOnTime
Public Sub kickDog()
'   Code to execute on timer event
'******************************************
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.Cells(1, 1) = Not Me.Cells(1, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
'******************************************
    Debug.Print "woof!!"
    mOnTime.kickDog
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Me.Cells(1,1) = False
    Set mOnTime = New cOnTime
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set mOnTime = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative route which isn't specified by others here but, I think, would theoretically work is:

1. Register VBA object as an active object with a specified GUID
2. Launch a `PowerShell` (or binary) daemon to connect to the object with specified GUID and call a specified method on that object every n seconds.

**Pros:**

- Totally encapsulated

**Cons:**

- Launches external process
- Method likely has to be public (unless connection points can be abused)
- Potentially crash-prone

I haven't implemented such a solution yet but intend to on [`stdCOM` of `stdVBA` library](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/issues/50) if everything works out.